# Cannot install php-imap extension to php7.2 on centos 7

Tags: centos7, php-7.2, php-imap

I have problem with installing php-imap to php7.2 on centos 7. When I run `yum install php-imap` I get this:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror                                                                                                                                                                   Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile                                                                                                                                                       * base: mirror.alpha-labs.net
 * centos-qemu-ev: mirror.imt-systems.com
 * centos-sclo-rh: mirror.alpix.eu
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirror.imt-systems.com
 * epel: www.nic.funet.fi
 * extras: mirror.alpha-labs.net
 * remi-safe: mirror.awanti.com
 * updates: mirror.alpix.eu                                                                                                                                                                     Resolving Dependencies                                                                                                                                                                          --> Running transaction check                                                                                                                                                                   ---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.4.16-9.el7 will be installed                                                                                                                                   --> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64 for package: php-imap-5.4.16-9.el7.x86_64                                                                                                --> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-64 for package: php-imap-5.4.16-9.el7.x86_64                                                                                                     --> Finished Dependency Resolution                                                                                                                                                              Error: Package: php-imap-5.4.16-9.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Installed: php-common-7.2.24-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php72)
               php(zend-abi) = 20170718-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64                                                                                                                                                      Error: Package: php-imap-5.4.16-9.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20100412-64
           Installed: php-common-7.2.24-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php72)
               php(api) = 20170718-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20100412-64                                                                                                                                                            You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem                                                                                                                                    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I dont know how to fix this, I have searched fix for this but havent found any,
here is also my repo list:

```
repo id                                                                         repo name                                                                                                 status
Softaculous/7/x86_64                                                            Virtualizor Repo                                                                                               9
Softaculous-extra/7/x86_64                                                      Virtualizor-Extra-Repo                                                                                         0
base/7/x86_64                                                                   CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                           10,097
centos-qemu-ev/7/x86_64                                                         CentOS-7 - QEMU EV                                                                                            87
centos-sclo-rh/x86_64                                                           CentOS-7 - SCLo rh                                                                                         8,763
centos-sclo-sclo/x86_64                                                         CentOS-7 - SCLo sclo                                                                                         824
epel/x86_64                                                                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                            13,456
extras/7/x86_64                                                                 CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                            305
mysql-connectors-community/x86_64                                               MySQL Connectors Community                                                                                   131
mysql-tools-community/x86_64                                                    MySQL Tools Community                                                                                        100
mysql56-community/x86_64                                                        MySQL 5.6 Community Server                                                                                   496
remi-safe                                                                       Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                 3,621
updates/7/x86_64                                                                CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                           738
repolist: 38,627
```

Answer (score 2):

I found how to install php-imap for php7.2m, I runned command `yum --enablerepo=remi-php72 install php-imap` what did its trick

Comment: Better to keep the repository enabled, as it only provides PHP, for additional extensions and update, see the Wizard; https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Comment: Hi @RemiCollet just curious. I have a PHP 8.1.6 version, but when I run php81-imap, it failss due to the fact that your plugin moves to 8.1.20. How can I force install it?

Comment: See https://forum.remirepo.net/viewtopic.php?id=1966